# Sending data between asp.net page & Popup page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a form where user selects 'fruit's from a popup form. I am using javascript to open the popup and query string to pass the text control id & hidden field id to the popup window.

How can I securely passed these parameters ? I am thinking about using Session but that would require a postback.

**Edit**
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try passing parameter using query string.. but try using Encrypted Querystring values to secure your data..  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/urlquerystring-encryption.aspx

Comment: That seems a lot of work for a simple task, do you advice using session ?

Comment: there is not so much effort needed to use encrypted querystring, as it is demonstrated in the article.. i don't recommend using sessions because "ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session". instead of a page request.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any of following methods.

1. Use a query string.
2. Get HTTP POST information from the source page.
3. Use session state.
4. Create public properties in the source page and access the property
   values in the target page.
5. Get control information in the target page from controls in the
   source page.

for more information,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

Comment: Can you tell me more about HTTP POST & when to use it?

Comment: in your case POST will be helpfull if you are do a postback and do some serverside task and then open the popup using client side script.